# XML Name Space Not Formating Correctly

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

Building an XML XDocument to push to web service and the root element needs namespace values this is what the XML form should look like....

```
<shipment-feed xmlns="http://seller.marketplace.sears.com/oms/v5" 

xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://seller.marketplace.sears.com/oms/v5 asn.xsd ">
<shipment>
<header>
<asn-number>00601780002</asn-number>
<po-number>0060180</po-number>
<po-date>2009-09-26</po-date>
</header>
<detail>
<tracking-number>UPS1XXX</tracking-number>
<ship-date>2001-01-01</ship-date>
<shipping-carrier>UPS</shipping-carrier>
<shipping-method>GROUND</shipping-method>
<package-detail>
<line-number>1</line-number>
<item-id>AB12345678912345456789123456789CD</item-id>
<quantity>1</quantity>
</package-detail>
</detail>
</shipment>
</shipment-feed>
```

This is the xml that I'm getting....

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shipment-feed xmlns="http://seller.marketplace.sears.com/oms/v5" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsischemalocation="http://seller.marketplace.sears.com/oms/v5 asn.xsd">
  <shipment xmlns="">
    <header>
      <asn-number>2824565201311</asn-number>
      <po-number>2824565</po-number>
      <po-date>2013-11-14</po-date>
    </header>
    <details>
      <tracking-number>579040914892</tracking-number>
      <ship-date>2013-11-14</ship-date>
      <shipping-carrier>FEDEX</shipping-carrier>
      <shipping-method>Ground</shipping-method>
      <package-details>
        <line-number>1</line-number>
        <item-id>LTH7XB1MW-EA</item-id>
        <quantity>3</quantity>
      </package-details>
    </details>
  </shipment>
  <shipment xmlns="">
    <header>
      <asn-number>2821596201311</asn-number>
      <po-number>2821596</po-number>
      <po-date>2013-11-13</po-date>
    </header>
    <details>
      <tracking-number>9405515901119923380663</tracking-number>
      <ship-date>2013-11-14</ship-date>
      <shipping-carrier>USPS</shipping-carrier>
      <shipping-method>Priority Mail</shipping-method>
      <package-details>
        <line-number>1</line-number>
        <item-id>CWD93151-EA</item-id>
        <quantity>6</quantity>
      </package-details>
      <package-details>
        <line-number>2</line-number>
        <item-id>CWD93901-EA</item-id>
        <quantity>4</quantity>
      </package-details>
    </details>
  </shipment>
</shipment-feed>
```

This is the C# code I created....

```
XNamespace ns1 = "http://seller.marketplace.sears.com/oms/v5";
XNamespace ns2 = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";
XNamespace ns3 = "http://seller.marketplace.sears.com/oms/v5 asn.xsd";
XDocument doc = new XDocument();    
XElement root = new XElement(ns1 + "shipment-feed",
                             new XAttribute("xmlns" , "http://seller.marketplace.sears.com/oms/v5"),
                             new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"),
                             new XAttribute("xsi" + "schemalocation", "http://seller.marketplace.sears.com/oms/v5 asn.xsd"));


doc.Add(root);
int x = 1;
foreach (SearsOrder s in SearsList)
{
    XElement shipment = new XElement("shipment",                
                        new XElement("header",
                            new XElement("asn-number", s.asnnumber),
                            new XElement("po-number", s.ponumber),
                            new XElement("po-date", s.podate)),
                        new XElement("details",
                            new XElement("tracking-number", s.trackingnum),
                            new XElement("ship-date", s.shipdate),
                            new XElement("shipping-carrier", s.carrier),
                            new XElement("shipping-method", s.method),
                            s.orderitems.Select(i => new XElement("package-details",
                                    new XElement("line-number", x++),
                                    new XElement("item-id", i.itemid),
                                    new XElement("quantity", i.quantity)))                            
            ));

    doc.Root.Add(shipment);
    x = 1;
}
```

The fist problem is the first child node  I'm not seeing where that is coming from because that node is not even declared until the foreach loop. I was under the impression that I was only adding attributes to the root element.

and the other problem is removing the xml declaration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sort of the thing is the problem:

```
new XElement("shipment", ...)
```

You want the `shipment` elements to be in the `"http://seller.marketplace.sears.com/oms/v5"` namespace - so you need to make that explicit. That won't show up in the resulting XML directly, because they'll inherit that as the *default* namespace specified in the root. Basically, wherever you're creating an element, you probably want to use `ns1`. So:

```
new XElement(ns1 + "shipment", new XElement(ns1 + "header", ...), ...)
```

To understand more about why this is required, you should read up on [namespace defaulting](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/#defaulting) in the XML Namespaces specification.

> and the other problem is removing the xml declaration

So add an [`XDeclaration`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdeclaration.aspx) to the `XDocument`:

```
XDocument doc = new XDocument(new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"))
```

Comment: Thanks Jon for the link. From the xml example form from sears api faq page it does not show the xml declaration so thats why i didn't put a XDeclaration in the document but it shows up as default. What I'm trying to do is get the file exactly as shown in the example.

Comment: @zerodoc: I would be very surprised if the XML declaration were actually an issue.

Comment: ok thanks, btw adding the namespace to all the XElements got rid of the <node xmlns"">. Just wanted to make sure my xml document was formated right before I opened a case to sears about not being able to upload the xml document.

Comment: @zerodoc: It's not really a *formatting* matter - it's a *semantic* matter of which namespace the elements are in. Glad it's worked for you though.